# Get count of multiple files loaded in one statment

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to get a total amount of all rows in multiple files, which are saved as a QVD. Actually, with one file I would accomplish this like that:

```
data:
LOAD count(id) AS counter FROM data.qvd (qvd);
LET number = Peek('counter');
```

Of course, I know that I also can use `RowNo()` or `Count()` the whole table in one command, but I want to try this with that solution.

Now when I try to fetch multiple files in one statement, as shown below, I always get only the count of the last loaded file and not the total:

```
data_multiple:
LOAD count(id) AS counter FROM data_*.qvd (qvd);
LET number_multiple = Peek('counter');
```

Now my question is how do I get the full amount of rows and not only the last one.

**What I tried so far**

I already tried to rearrange the statement like this:

```
data:
LOAD id FROM data_*.qvd (qvd);

LOAD Count(id) AS counter Resident data;
LET number = Peek('counter');
```

But I do get still the same result. Is there some way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked the same [question on the official Qlik Community page](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Scripting/Get-count-of-multiple-files-loaded-in-one-statment/m-p/1512702). There I received an answer:

```
let total_number = 0;

for each file in filelist('D:\Data\data_*.qvd') 
    QVDRecords: load QvdNoOfRecords('$(file)') as Counter, '$(file)' as Source autogenerate 1; 
    total_number = total_number + Peek('Counter');
next 

trace QVD: $(total_number);
```